# Immediate actions during other actions

Tags: dnd-3.5e

As we all know, immediate actions are just like swift actions, but can be performed outside of one's turn.

> However, unlike a swift action, an immediate action can be performed at any time - even if it's not your turn.

*However*, it is still unclear if one can use an immediate action during someone else's action.

For example:

A monster swings at a conjurer.

- Can conjurer *abrupt jaunt* outside monster's reach right after the attack was rolled, thus wasting an attack?
- What about right after the damage was rolled, but not yet applied?
- What about casting *celerity* and *baleful transposition* on yourself and monster's ally so the monster would hit his ally, given high enough attack roll?

Let's complicate a bit with a complex, full-round action on a monster's side.

- Can one use immediate action in between attacks in *full attack*?
- What about after movement part of a *charge*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## All about Immediate Actions

An [immediate action](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#immediateActions), according to the SRD, is used as follows

> Much like a swift action, an immediate action consumes a very small amount of time, but represents a larger expenditure of effort and energy than a free action. However, unlike a swift action, an immediate action can be performed at any time — even if it's not your turn. Casting *feather fall* is an immediate action, since the spell can be cast at any time.
>
> Using an immediate action on your turn is the same as using a swift action, and counts as your swift action for that turn. You cannot use another immediate action or a swift action until after your next turn if you have used an immediate action when it is not currently your turn (effectively, using an immediate action before your turn is equivalent to using your swift action for the coming turn). You also cannot use an immediate action if you are flat-footed.

And that's pretty much it.

An immediate action *isn't* like taking a standard action to [ready](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialInitiativeActions.htm#ready). An immediate action can't be taken *in response* to another event then occur *before* the event it's responding to. There's no last-in,-first-out in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*.

Further, while some events are viewed as having discrete steps at the gaming table, some of those events *don't* actually have all those steps according to the game, and therefore must be resolved before immediate actions can be taken.

Unlike many trading card games, there's often no specific declare phases or discrete steps (e.g. a creature doesn't pick a target *then* make an attack roll *then* roll damage, allowing responses to each). A creature *does something* that needs to be resolved (e.g. make an attack, cast a spell) before something else can occur. Immediate actions, then, *can't* be taken while the other creature has an event unresolved, but an immediate action can be taken *between* events.

The DM must determine *when* an event has multiple steps that can be interrupted (during which creatures can take immediate actions) *and* when an event is finally resolved, but the game provides some guidance.

### Event: Attack Roll

An [attack roll](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#attackRoll)

> represents your attempt to strike your opponent on your turn in a round. When you make an attack roll, you roll a d20 and add your attack bonus. (Other modifiers may also apply to this roll.) If your result equals or beats the target’s Armor Class, you hit and deal damage.

Thus once the attack roll is made, an immediate action *can't* taken until damage is dealt. The attack roll, once made, determines *both* whether an attack hit *and* inflicts damage. Note that this differs from Ernir's answer to this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21862/immediate-action-right-after-damage).

### Event: Saving Throw

A saving throw *is* resolved discretely. There are opportunities for decisions during saving throws.  [For example](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#savingThrow), "A creature can voluntarily forego a saving throw and willingly accept a spell’s result." This opportunity for decision-making permits immediate actions to be taken when rolling a saving throw (e.g. the psionic power [*evade burst*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/evadeBurst.htm))

### Specific Exceptions

Some special abilities interrupt events that can't otherwise be interrupted. For example, the [elan](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/monsters/elan.htm)'s supernatural ability resilience says, "As an immediate action, an elan can reduce the damage he is about to take by 2 points for every 1 power point spent." If the elan weren't about to take damage from an attack, he couldn't use this ability, so this ability allows the elan to take an immediate action before damage is inflicted during an attack.

---

**Example 1**
A monster makes an attack roll *versus* a conjurer with the supernatural ability abrupt jaunt alternative class feature and who has prepared several spells with immediate action casting times.

- The conjurer *can't* take an immediate action *after* the attack roll's made but *before* the conjurer knows if it landed.
- The conjurer *can't* take an immediate action *after* the attack roll's made but *before* damage is dealt.
- The conjurer *can* take an immediate action *after* a creature's attack roll has resolved and before me makes another attack roll when the creature makes multiple attack rolls during a full attack action.
- The DM must determine if the conjurer can take an immediate action between the movement and the attack of a charge. (*PH* 154 says, "Charging is a special full-round action that allows you to move... and attack during the action.") Reminder: It's already *really* tough out there for melee characters.

**Example 2**
Consider this text from the 2nd-level Clr spell *close wounds* [conj] (*SpC* 48), which has a casting time of 1 immediate action,

> If you cast this spell immediately after the subject takes damage, it effectively prevents the damage. It would keep alive someone who had just dropped to –10 hit points, for example, leaving the character at negative hit points but stable.

The game *must* make a special case for the spell *close wounds* because otherwise the spell wouldn't do what the game wanted it to do--keep folks alive. *Without* that text, the damage would resolve, the creature would die, and the spell *close wounds* wouldn't be anything more than a weak, off-turn *cure* spell.

Comment: With respect to the end of example 2 there, damage doesn't resolve. It just happens in D&D. Rather than looking at it like MTG stacks, the spell Close Wounds actually relies on the damage being dealt in order to close the wounds and heal said damage. So even if you died from the initial hit, the spell would undo the damage that killed you, meaning you aren't dead. You were for a split second, but that doesn't matter because the reason you died doesn't exist anymore. 

That's why the text says it effectively prevents the damage, same effective results.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli My use of the word *resolve* the last example is in the sense of *assessed* (i.e. what happens to the damaged creature because of the damage) rather than in a *Magic: The Gathering* sense. (Your comment initially sounds like it planned on disagreeing; I don't think it ended up that way, though. Are you agreeing and just clarifying or am I misreading?)

Comment: We're in agreement. The terminology for damage resolving was a little misleading though. Yes, we are agreeing, and I'm just clarifying for any MTG players who read that and immediately started thinking stack priority.

Comment: The *Miniatures Handbook* includes in its Skirmish Glossary a definition of **Immediate** that, in part, says, "This action may interrupt other actions, taking effect just before they do. The last immediate action declared takes place first" (121). That glossary is for the skirmish rules included in the *Handbook* and doesn't apply to normal *D&D 3.5* play. (Q.v. [this 2021 GITP thread](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?639293-Immediate-actions-can-interrupt).)